# How to start GlassFish Server on Windows 7?

Tags: glassfish

I installed GlassFish Server in C:\glassfish3 directory.

When I type "dir" in c:\glassfish3\bin directory the files are listed just fine.

[image]

But when I type asadmin I get "The system cannot find the path specified."

What might be wrong?

How am I going to start GlassFish server?

-- Edit --

Also, after Installation I get:

Creating domain

---

Executing command :C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile - create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 domain1 
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile - create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 domain1 The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: have u tried asadmin start-domain -v ?

Comment: Yes, does not work either.

Comment: asadmin start-domain should work for your default domain. Pls refer to step by step instructions, in case your classpath is missing http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0186/fvjgo/

Comment: remove the line `@echo off` from `asadmin.bat` and try again. that will show more on why it fails.

Comment: @muratgu Apparently, it is looking for C:\Program Files\Java\bin\java however my Java Installation is in a different folder. Thanks.

Comment: How can I tell GlassFish to look for the correct path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glassfish requires jdk6 or 7 already installed. type `java -version` on command line. if it's not working then you need to install it.

alternatively you can tell glassfish to look for a particular jdk, by modifying `C:\glassfish3\glassfish\config\asenv.bat` -- but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, I already have Java installed. I changed the bat file. set JAVA="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\java" Now it works.